# Was Pontius Pilate justified in his actions?

Tags: christianity, values, morals

Was Pontius Pilate justified in his sentencing of Jesus to the cross?

Some, like the Ethiopian church view him as a saint, while others believe that he is in hell. Pontius Pilate was given the sudden burden choice in deciding the fate of a popular religious leader. He was forced to choose, between his own moral grounds, and the pressing crowd outside, rallied by the Jewish leaders to kill Jesus.

He succumbed and sentenced Jesus to the cross, but while some may view him as a traitor, I think we should also see that if he said no, he may be fired, and riots would break out. So maybe Pilate isn't as bad as he seems?

On the other hand, he sentences Jesus to crucifixion, under no reasonable charge. He goes against his own values, reluctant to kill Jesus, but in the end, he succumbed and let Jesus die.

So was he the bad guy, or was the fault mostly on the Priest who rallied the crowd?

[image]

Comment: Well, another example is Brutus, who has the choice of deciding to kill his friend or not. He has the power to warn Caesar, but doesn't, putting his government duties, (the Senate backed him up, trying to build a government based on a republic not empire.) and putting government before values, for Caesar had treated Brutus like a son. This causes many today to argue wether Brutus was a good guy or a bad guy in helping murdering Caesar.

Comment: that wouldn't necessarily be an *injustice*, but you are right it is not in the spirit of friendship. honestly, you won't get well referenced answers here.

Comment: Based on which moral framework? If you do not name specifics, basically every *opinion* would be equally valid as an answer. That is something we want to avoid here.

Comment: Its a good question. Replace Jesus by Julian Assange and it becomes topical. Or by Socrates and it becomes philosophical

Comment: i misremembered the essay i link to below, but it might help you think clearly

Comment: The "bad guys" were obviously the priests... as always. But the "priests" wrote history, and thus PP was denigrated.

Comment: A good book is available: Aldo Schiavone, [Pontius Pilate: Deciphering a Memory (2016)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Pontius_Pilate_Deciphering_a_Memory/nlJ8DAAAQBAJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was thinking of

> Sometimes, she adds, it will be immediately clear whether what is
> being said is true or false if we use more precise terms of moral
> evaluation such as just and unjust. Whether abortion is just is not
> immediately clear to many people, but the injustice of the judicial
> execution of those known to be innocent is clear. This is the example
> that Anscombe uses most often. The suggestion that deliberately
> killing tens of thousands of innocent non-combatants, including
> children, would be permissible is a vague one. The suggestion that it
> would be just is clearly false. The suggestion that it would be useful
> might be clearly true. If we used the more precise terms just and
> useful then we could at least see that the debate was between the
> relative importance of justice and utility. If we insist on using
> words such as permissible and wrong then we might fail to understand
> what is at issue. It is largely clarity that Anscombe urges
> philosophers to strive for.

https://iep.utm.edu/anscombe/

> That being said, it is worth repeating that Anscombe does not reject
> all talk of moral obligation... (In contrast, she regards murder as
> forbidden to all people in all circumstances.)... Anscombe might say that we must not murder because God has forbidden it. Or she might regard it as ruled out by considerations of justice. Or by a mystical perception of the value of human life. In “Murder and the Morality of Euthanasia” she writes that, “The prohibition [on murder] is **so basic that it is difficult to answer the question as to why** murder is intrinsically wrongful” (Anscombe 2005, p. 266).

Is the murder of God and Caeser morally impermisible? You don't need a moral absolute to think so.

---

https://sites.pitt.edu/%7Emthompso/readings/mmp.pdf

> [some philosophers claim] it might be a step in his moral education
> to frame a moral principle that... in such and such circumstances one
> **ought** to procure the judicial condemnation of the innocent. And that
> is my complaint.

Emphasis added.

Her point in the essay seems to be that we need to be aware of the difference between vice, injustice, and wrong. Justice is never wrong, but injustice may not be, even-though some things are absolutely wrong, and basically so, without any reason why.